# Can not generate certbot certificate using docker image : EOFError

Tags: docker, ssh, certbot

I am trying to generate SSL certificates using certbot docker image.
here is my command.

```
docker run --rm --name temp_certbot \
    -v /data/certbot/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
    -v /data/certbot/www:/tmp/letsencrypt \
    -v /data/certbot/www/log:/var/log \
    certbot/certbot \
    certonly --agree-tos --renew-by-default --manual \
    --email my_email@emailprovider.com --dry \
    -d *.my_domain.dev
```

I am running this command on with bash on debian server after connect to it throught SSH.
Certbot should prompt and wait for me to press "Enter" to validate the challenge.
But it goes ahead and dont wait showing the "EOFError" as swhon here :

[image]

Can you help please?

Comment: If you are facing a problem with an existing Docker image, please open an issue in the official bug tracker

Comment: I think that is issue is related to the fact that I am usin SSL because if I run this command on my local ubuntu it works fine

Comment: I think you are missing the `-it` option for docker run which allows you to run the command interactively.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by pat :
I think you are missing the `-it` option for docker run which allows you to run the command interactively